# Docker django error: http: invalid Host header

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a project that is launched from docker on a vps server and everything works fine there, and I also wrote another project using identical technologies, after which I simply replaced the data in .env and tried to run it on another vps with an error:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d --build
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                                                                                                                      
http: invalid Host header
```

I have already checked the firewall several times, all ports are open, I also followed the vps link and received the standard nginx page, changed the port configuration in docker compos, the error is still active, I also monitored the connection to the server there, everything is fine on port 80, it connects without problems
Here are my settings:
docker-compose.prod.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn hello_django.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:13.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
  nginx-proxy:
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    build: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8443:443
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    depends_on:
      - web
  acme-companion:
    image: nginxproxy/acme-companion
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.proxy-companion
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - acme:/etc/acme.sh
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
  certs:
  html:
  vhost:
  acme:
```

Dockerfile.prod:

```
###########
# BUILDER #
###########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine as builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# lint
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install flake8==3.9.2
COPY . .

# install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt


#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/staticfiles
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/mediafiles
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add libpq
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

# copy entrypoint.prod.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.prod.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g'  $APP_HOME/entrypoint.prod.sh
RUN chmod +x  $APP_HOME/entrypoint.prod.sh

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app

# run entrypoint.prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/entrypoint.prod.sh"]
```

entrypoint.prod.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

exec "$@"
```

Here is the nginx setup:
Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginxproxy/nginx-proxy

COPY vhost.d/default /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default
COPY custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf
```

custom.conf:

```
client_max_body_size 10M;
```

default:

```
    location /static/ {
  alias /home/app/web/staticfiles/;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}

location /media/ {
  alias /home/app/web/mediafiles/;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

Perhaps someone has already solved a similar problem or knows how to solve it? I will be grateful for your help